# docker - problems with my minecraft server dont save files

Tags: server, files, docker, openjdk, container

I try to run my minecraft server on my rootserver.
To do this Im use docker with the openjkd:8-alpine with the following commandline:
`docker run -p 25565:25565 --name spigot_server --volume /home/bdevgw/servers/minecraft/testdata:/data:rw --rm openjdk:8-alpine java -Xmx4G -jar data/spigot-1.12.2.jar`
So, what should I say? The server starts! But he stops after a second and tells me that I have to confirm the EULA but he haven't created any files. No eula.txt, no server.properties.
What do I have to change to make the server save any files?

I hope you can help me,
Nils.

Comment: First, check that your volume mapping is correct on both sides, anything your container saves under `/data` should appear in your `testdata` folder. Second, if that doesn't work, you may run `docker exec -it spigot_server bash` to get a shell inside your container to poke around

Comment: what would be the "coorect maaping"? Im new with docker and unix and happy enough that my teamspeak already runs.

Comment: Think of your container as a different, disposable linux machine: To have persistent data, you can map volumes of your 'outside' machine into the container which you already do via `--volume`. Idk where minecraft saves it's data normally: But the part after the `:` should point to the minecraft datapath. This migh be something like `/root/minecraft`, or somewhere under `/opt`. Try using the shell to locate it

Comment: Ihave my server in /home/bdevgw/servers/minecraft/testdata. so how would look the correct connamdline? I realy have no idea what i have to do :(
Maybe I understand the point when I see it :)
Than I can do it by myself next time ;)

Comment: OK problem solved, I use screen now :)

Comment: If you mean screen the terminal multiplexer, how does that relate to this issue? And if you have a solution for your problem, please post it as an answe and accept it for other people with the same or similar issue to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i just needed docker to run my server in background so that I can close the terminal without killing the server.
After googling and asking frinds I found "Screen" which works fine for me.
I installed jdk on my system and then I run this command:
`screen -R -S mcserver`
This commands creates the virtual terminal or, if it already exists opens it.
Then I can manage my server, close my PuTTY seassion or detach from the terminal and do other things without killing the server.

I know that there are other uses for docker but for my problem this works fine :)